# Error when trying to preview PDF documents with TeXlipse

Tags: miktex, eclipse, yap

I'm using TeXlipse (LaTeX plugin for eclipse) and I want to preview my LaTeX document.

I have configured yap in the viewer settings.
When I push the preview button I get an error in the console:

```
Error: Project output file format not set in project: thesis.
```

I don't understand the message, because I set the output file and it works, because when I save, the auto save compile function produces the correct output pdf

Here is my `.texlipse` file

```
#TeXlipse project settings
#Thu Jun 21 20:51:48 CEST 2012
markTmpDer=true
builderNum=2
outputDir=
makeIndSty=
bibrefDir=
outputFormat=pdf
tempDir=tmp/
mainTexFile=template.tex
outputFile=main.pdf
langSpell=de
markDer=true
srcDir=
```

and my `.project` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>thesis</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>net.sourceforge.texlipse.builder.TexlipseBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>net.sourceforge.texlipse.builder.TexlipseNature</nature>
    </natures>
    <linkedResources>
        <link>
            <name>.tex</name>
            <type>1</type>
            <location>C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/tools/.tex</location>
        </link>
        <link>
            <name>mybib.bib</name>
            <type>1</type>
            <location>C:/Users/thunder/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/bibtex/bib/ijqc/mybib.bib</location>
        </link>
    </linkedResources>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

[YAP is a DVI viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yet_Another_Previewer), not a PDF viewer. Therefore it cannot open your PDF file, as the error message informs you:

[image]